# ¿Como almacenar los datos múltiples que provienen en formato de array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**ACTUALIZADO**

**Dentro de mi formulario poseo una tabla que permite agregar/eliminar dinámicamente campos de entrada.** En esta misma tabla puedo insertar tantas herramientas como desee, quiero aclarar en esta misma tabla participan y se relacionan **2 entidades (TOOL-INSERT), con una relación de uno a muchos.**

al intentar guardar el fomulario recibo el siguiente error que proviene de mi tabla dinamica:

> message: "Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `tools` (`code_tool`, `insert_id`, `position`) values (www, effeee, 01))"

Las dudas que tengo son las siguientes:
**¿Como capturar los datos múltiples ingresados en mi formulario a través de mi tabla dinámica?**
**¿Como guardar los datos múltiples que provienen en formato de array?**

A continuacion una imagen de mi formulario

[image: form-tabla dinamica]

Como mencione anteriormente en la imagen existen campos que pertenecen a la entidad **TOOL (posición/herramienta) y campos que pertenecen a la entidad INSERT(inserto/calidad)**

modelo Tool:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tool extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'insert_id', 'position', 'code_tool', 'type', 'category', 'status', 'description', 'reason'
    ];   

    public function inserts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Insert::class);
    }    

    public function pieces()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Piece::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

modelo Insert:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Insert extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'code_insert', 'quality', 'type', 'category', 'status', 'description', 'reason'
    ];

    public function tool()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Insert::class);
    } 
}
```

Este es mi formulario:

```
<div class="row">
    {!! Form::model($piece, [
        'route' => $piece->exists ? ['admin.pieces.update', $pieces->id] : 'admin.pieces.store',   
        'method' => $piece->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
    ]) !!} 

     <div class="col-md-6">    
        <div class="box box-primary">            
            <div class="box-header with-border ">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalles del Legajo</h3>     
            </div>  
            <div class="box-body">  

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="dynamicTable">  
                <tr>
                    <th>Posición</th>
                    <th>Herramienta</th>                 
                    <th>Inserto</th>                 
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="position[]" placeholder="Posicion" class="form-control select2" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="code_tool[]" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="code_insert[]" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control" /></td>                                  
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add More</button></td>  
                </tr>  
            </table> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}    
</div>
```

**Entiendo que primero se debe crear el inserto, luego crear la herramienta ya que la tabla tools tiene un campo insert_id.**

En mi controlador en el metodo store estoy tratando de recorrer el array de la siguiente manera:

**ACTUALIZADO 2P**
controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                //  Transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();                                    

                $position    = $request->position;
                $code_tool   = $request->code_tool;
                $code_insert = $request->code_insert;
                $quality     = $request->quality;                 

                for($count = 0; $count < count($position); $count++)
                {
                    $insert = array(                        
                        'code_insert' => $code_insert[$count],
                        'quality'     => $quality[$count]

                    );

                    $insert = new Insert();
                    $insert->code_insert =  $code_insert[$count];
                    $insert->quality = $quality[$count];

                    if($insert->save()){
                        $tool = array(
                        'position'    => $position[$count],
                        'code_tool'   => $code_tool[$count],
                        'insert_id'   => $insert->id
                        );
                        $tool_data[] = $tool;
                    }                 
                }
                // dd($tool_data);             

                Tool::insert($tool_data);

                $gag     = Gag::create($request->all());
                $program = Program::create($request->all()); 

                $piece = $program->piece()->create([
                    'denomination' => $request['denomination'],
                    'code'         => $request['code'],
                    'time'         => $request['time'],
                    'part_piece'   => $request['part_piece'],
                    'gag_id'       => $gag->id
                ]);

                $piece->tools()->sync($request->get(''));

                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }    
    }
```

Agregando un dd($tool_data); inspecciono la consola justamente en pestana network,
obtengo lo siguiente:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "position" => "01"
    "code_tool" => "www"
    "insert_id" => array:2 [
      "code_insert" => "effeee"
      "quality" => "de3"
    ]
  ]
]
```

**¿me podrian ayudar, explicar como capturar los datos desde mi tabla dinamica, recorrer el array y guardarlo correctamente?**

Comment: Asumiendo que está bien validado: `Insert::createMany($request->addMore)`

Comment: @IGP realice algunos cambios en el metodo store recibo el siguiente error: ```message: "Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into tools (code_tool, insert_id, position) values (www, effeee, 01))"```

Comment: Pon `dd($tool_data)` antes del insert y ve que te arroja.

Comment: @IGP podrias fijarte mi actualización, agregue lo que me indicaste, mi problema es no saber si estoy recorriendo el array de manera correcta ya que son campos que inserto dinamicamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en que `inser_id` es un array.

```php
...
$insert = array(                        
  'code_insert' => $code_insert[$count],
  'quality'     => $quality[$count]
);
```

Debes primero guardar el `$insert` en tu base de datos, y luego si guardar el `ID` de ese objeto en el atributo `insert_id` de tu modelo `Tool`.

```php
$insert = new Insert();
$insert->code_insert =  $code_insert[$count];
$insert->quality = $quality[$count];

if($insert->save()){
    $tool = array(
       'position'    => $position[$count],
       'code_tool'   => $code_tool[$count],
       'insert_id'   => $insert->id
     );
     $tool_data[] = $tool;
}
...

Tool::insert($tool_data);                   
DB::commit();
```

Debes guardar primero el `$insert` porque si no, no sabrás que ID es el que se le asignara a ese objeto.

Comment: gracias por ayudar. Una pregunta para entenderte mejor, tendria q modificar el metodo store? Porque veo los cambios que me indicas y por ejemplo no se si quitar el foreach

Comment: precisamente me refiero a eso: '''
                $position    = $request->position;
                $code_tool   = $request->code_tool;
                $code_insert = $request->code_insert;
                $quality     = $request->quality;                 

                for($count = 0; $count < count($position); $count++)
                {'''

Comment: Ese método `for` se mantiene solo que debes eliminar el ` Insert::insert($insert_data);` porque guardaras previamente cuando usas el `save()`

Comment: Ok @Diego Mesa, realizo las modificaciones luego te comento.

Comment: Mira @Diego Mesa, con los cambios que me indicaste y modifcando el metodo store funciona perfecto. Ahora no comprendo como asociar esas herramientas a mi pieza, ya que la relación de pieza - herramientas es de muchos a muchos.

Comment: me refiero a esto: ```$piece->tools()->sync($request->get(''));```, aca tengo cuatro campos: ```position[], code_tool[], code_insert[], quality[]``` que es la informacion que ingreso dinamicamente. Como asocio esa herramienta a la pieza ?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz, es la misma situación, el helper `insert()` solo lo debes usar cuando no requieres usar más los objetos creados, para tu caso debes usar `save()`,  en vez de `$tool_data[] = $tool;` guardas solo el id con `if($tool->save()){ $tool_data[] =  $tool->id};` asi envias un array con solo `ids` a `$piece->tools()->sync($tool_data)`. Enviado asi algo como `..->sync([1,2,3])`